# Flow Dependent Picklist Values

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I cannot figure out how to store the selection from a Dependent Picklist component. I am using just a basic Opportunity with the StageName and a child picklist, Status Reason.

I've explored the [documentation from Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_dependentpicklists.htm), but I guess I just don't understand it.

Here is how I have the component set up:

- API Name: CloneStage
- Object API Name: Opportunity
- Picklist 1 API Name: StageName
- Picklist 2 API Name: Status_Reason__c
- Picklist 1 Label: Status
- Picklist 1 Required: {!$GlobalConstant.True}
- Picklist 1 Value: New
- Picklist 2 Label: Status Reason
- Picklist 2 Required: {!$GlobalConstant.False}
- Picklist 2 Value: [blank]

How can I expose the values the rep selects so I can use it in an assignment element in the next step?

--edit
When I try to define the "Store Output Values" it gives me errors. I try to set them this way:

- Object API Name: Opportunity
- Picklist 1 API Name: StageName

Even just that much gives me errors on both fields.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to save value that user select on picklist one and picklist 2 to use it for next step?

create 2 variable. and assign them under "Store Output Value" section - Picklist 1 value, Picklist 2 value.

also for picklist 1 do you only want "NEW" as value? or you want to show all values? if you want to show all value then leave "Picklist 1 Value: New" field blank.

[image]